# How can I create a pop-up window using a new page as the pop-up source?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pop up a panel when a "createbutton" is clicked, I am using a panel and adding some textbox and buttons inside the panel. I am able to make the pop up panel by designing it in the same page where the createbutton is present. can I make the pop up in a separate page and make it pop up when I click the createbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gokul,

Yes, you can put the panel in a separate page and make it appear when you click the create button. Here's one alternative (not my favorite but it doesn't depend on anything extra besides standard javascript):

- When you click the "create button" open a new browser window resized exactly to match the panel's size. This can be done with javascript easily as follows:

  > <
  >   input onclick="javascript:window.open('page.aspx','title','status=0,toolbar=0,width=350,height=250');"
  >   type="button" value="Create" />
- On the page that you popped up containing the panel (pagecontainingPanel.aspx - according to my example), you can have code to close the window once you perform some action. For example, if you have a button that's supposed to save some data to the database and comeback to the parent page, you could do something like:

> {

```
  ///Perform server side process. If successfully executed close this window. 
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  if(EverythingOK) 
        { 
           StringBuilder cstext2 = new StringBuilder();
  cstext2.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function CloseMe() {");
  cstext2.Append("window.close();} </");
  cstext2.Append("script>");
  cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname2, cstext2.ToString(), false);
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You could create an iframe and then set the source as the panel you're creating.

Let's say you have two html pages panel.html and main.html

Your panel.html can simply be

```
<html>
   <body style="background-color:red">
      Hi!
   </body>
</html>
```

and your main.html

```
    <html>
    <body style="background-color:yellow">
        <iframe src="panel.html" style="height:300px;width:300px;border:0px;display:none;" id="myPanel"></iframe>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myPanel').style.display='block';return false">Show Panel</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This should show a yellow page with a hyperlink of "Show Panel".  When you click on Show Panel, it will show the iframe of your panel.html.

If you're using ASP.NET MVC, you can do this by creating a View that can be called down with some Ajax/JQuery code.  If you're looking for something along that approach, I can post some code for that.