# Page pop up in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

I am doing a pop up on my home page using the following link

```
<a href="CreateUser.aspx" target="_blank"

 onclick="window.open('CreateUser.aspx', 'windowname',

'width=500,height=400,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,directories=no,location=no'); return false">Create users</a>
```

But when this window is opened I am able to navigate in the home page, which I want to disable until user clicks ok or cancel in the create users page. How to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a pop-up window using a new page as the pop-up source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218158/how-can-i-create-a-pop-up-window-using-a-new-page-as-the-pop-up-source)

Comment: you can always search a bit here in SO for similar questions :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937591/window-open-as-modal-popup

Comment: Seems like you want to create a modal popup. You can use the ModalPopup extension of the Ajax Control Toolkit for this purpose. You can find a demo here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the specific aspect you were referring to, I believe you'd want to set showMenu to false.

Here is a method which includes the most commonly used options when opening a popup window:

```
openChildWindowWithDimensions = function(url, width, height, showMenu, canResize, showScrollbars) {
    var childWindow = window.open(url, "", "\"width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",menubar=" + (showMenu ? "1" : "0") + ",scrollbars=" + (showScrollbars ? "1" : "0") + ",resizable=" + (canResize ? "1" : "0") + "\"");
    if (childWindow){
        childWindow.resizeTo(width, height); //for IE9 bug
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most reliable way is to use javascript. There are a lot of examples on the internet on how to implement a modal popup. In particular: [Div as modal - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502435/div-as-modal-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Pop ups is a bad idea. They produce many problems. Why don't you try to make a div and put the contents of the pop up in it? jQueryUI can help you: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ And for the content, you can embedd it in a ASP.NET User Control, for example.

Comment: Why are popups a bad idea, and what are the many problems that they cause? Could you please elaborate on that statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a Modal, not a popup window.

- [ASP.NET Modal Example](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx)
- [What's a Modal Window?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)